# How to add occurrence of each entry to pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Let `df1` be a pandas data frame with a column of letters and a column of integers:

```
>>> k = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": numpy.random.choice([i for i in "abcde"], 10), 
    "b": numpy.random.choice(range(5), 10)
})
>>> k
   a  b
0  a  1
1  c  2
2  e  1
3  b  3
4  c  2
5  d  2
6  e  2
7  c  3
8  b  0
9  a  3
```

Using `value_counts()`, the counts of the letters are found:

```
>>> counts = k["a"].value_counts()
>>> counts
c    3
e    2
b    2
a    2
d    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

How to add each occurrance to the respective row? It should result in

```
>>> k
   a  b  count
0  a  1  2
1  c  2  3
2  e  1  2
[...]
9  a  3  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate to using `transform`:

First, you can extract the `value_counts()` into a dataframe:

`mycounts = k['a'].value_counts().rename_axis('a').reset_index(name = 'counts')`

The step above is useful in many different scenarios (and good to know in general).

Then, a left-join will put the value counts into the original dataframe:

`k = k.merge(mycounts, left_on = 'a', right_on = 'a', how = 'left')`

Comment: I like the merge approach but I feel it would be cleaner to introduce a `key` column on which to join instead of renaming the index

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `transform`

```
k['count']=k.groupby('a').a.transform('count')
k
Out[330]: 
   a  b  count
0  d  1      2
1  e  3      3
2  e  3      3
3  d  3      2
4  b  4      4
5  b  1      4
6  b  0      4
7  a  2      1
8  b  0      4
9  e  4      3
```